# Create a zip from folders retaining file structure including parent folders (and single files)

Tags: gulp, zip, glob, directory-structure, gulp-zip

I am trying to create a zip file from the following file structure:

```
-dist/bundle.js
-assets/[several subfolders with files]
-config.json
-bootstrap.js
```

I have used gulp-zip:

```
gulp.task('zip', ()=>{
return gulp.src(['dist/**/*.*', 'assets/**/*.*','config.json', 'bootstrap.js'])
    .pipe(zip('game.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('deploy'))
})
```

which results in:
game.zip with this structure:

```
-game
--[some assets subfolder]
--[other assets subfolder]
--[third assets subfolder]
--bundle.js
--bootstrap.js
--config.json
```

The files/folders should not be in a folder (game) but retain the structure they initially have, also assets and dist folders should also be in the structure.
Any solution that I can run from my package.json scripts node would be welcomed. (gulp/webpack/grunt/whatever)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this:

```
gulp.task('default', ()=>{
  return gulp.src(['dist/**/*.*', 'assets/**/*.*','config.json', 'bootstrap.js'], {base: '.'})
      .pipe(zip('game.zip'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('deploy'))
})
```

Simply adding the `{base: '.'}` option to gulp.src does what you want.  See [gulp base option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#optionsbase). Using `{base: '.'}` basically tells gulp to use all the directories in the `dest` location.  Otherwise the default operation is to remove directories before the globs.  So, in '`dist/**/*.*`' the `dist` folder would not be retained without the base option.

I don't know where you get a `game` folder, I never do.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Regarding the game folder I believe it is default behaviour for a zip folder to unzip to a folder with the name of the zip file itself. It turned out that the zip file I normally create manually by selecting files and folders and right clicking has the same behaviour. It does on my Mac anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post another solution that I found while searching the web (still accepting [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482287/3333019) solution as it is much shorter/simpler:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');

const output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/deploy/rosa.zip');
const archive = archiver('zip', {
store: true
//zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

// listen for all archive data to be written
// 'close' event is fired only when a file descriptor is involved
output.on('close', function() {
console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has 
closed.');
});

// This event is fired when the data source is drained no matter what was the 
data source.
// It is not part of this library but rather from the NodeJS Stream API.
// @see: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end
output.on('end', function() {
console.log('Data has been drained');
});

// good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking 
errors)
archive.on('warning', function(err) {
if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
  // log warning
} else {
  // throw error
  throw err;
}
});

// good practice to catch this error explicitly
archive.on('error', function(err) {
throw err;
});
// pipe archive data to the file
archive.pipe(output);

archive.directory('assets/', 'assets');
archive.directory('dist/', 'dist');
archive.file('bootstrap.js', {name: 'bootstrap.js'});
archive.file('config.json', {name: 'config.json'});
archive.finalize();
```

From: [Archiver js Docs](https://archiverjs.com/docs/)